# PHPBB logo only shows half

Tags: php, css, caching, phpbb3

Okay, guys.

- I'm about to make a forum, but my logo is only shown half.

Here is what it shows: http://i60.tinypic.com/5widdy.png

Here it´s what it's supposed to show: http://i61.tinypic.com/14ihnk9.png

I set my imageset.cfg to 'img_site_logo = logo.png*260*100', wich is the right size of the logo, and i cleaned the cache of the theme. I can't figure out whats wrong with it, so i hope you guys can help me :-) The theme i use is called 'modestus'.

Comment: did you use the editor in the ACP to change the size value or did you download the file and re-upload the edited version?

Answer (score -1):

First, try the following. Right click on the logo and click "inspect element" or whatever your browsers equivalent is, then a window with the page HTML and CSS should pop up, showing you exactly what CSS is being applied to it. Try checking and unchecking fields in the CSS window to test the applied style values to see if one of them is causing the problem. Highlight parent HTML elements and then do the same thing to their CSS just in case. If one of these resolves the issue, then look at the file that is being called (should look something like common.css or styles.css) and go into that file (phpbb/styles/yourstylename/thatfile.css) and search for the target element the style was being applied to to find the problem area. Comment it out with /* */ on either side of the statement and then refresh your style sheet and clear your cache from the ACP to check that it worked. You will need to refresh the page the logo appears on once you've refreshed the style and cleared the cache to see the changes sometimes.

If that doesn't work, open your image into an image editing software and verify that there is no transparent or white space on the edges of the image. If there is, crop it out and re-save.